# Why can't private class fields be deleted?

Tags: javascript, class, private, ecmascript-2022

It seems it's not possible to delete `#`private class fields. The syntax doesn't allow it.

```js
class Example {
    #privatefield = 'some_value';

    deleteField() {
        delete this.#privatefield;
    }
}
```

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Private fields can not be deleted
```

Does anyone know why? What is the rationale behind allowing deletion of normal properties but not of private class fields?

Comment: @JustinNimmo they are adopted as of ES2022 and [fully supported in all major browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#browser_compatibility). It is discussed in the [Delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#description) documentation.

Comment: @MichaelM. I think none of them quite did, though. Don't get me wrong, the answers are informative, but they just point to the fact the specification doesn't allow class field delition, and this fact is already in the question itself. The question is actually about why the language was designed in this way. Like, what kinds of problem are prevented by disallowing private class field deletion? In my opinion, it's not answered yet. Do you disagree?

Comment: It's an interesting question. I'm guessing there's not really an answer beyond "no one thought it was worth proposing". I have some thoughts about why no one would think it's worthwhile, but couldn't prove anything.

Answer (score 4):

First, this is not a bug. [MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields),

> It is a syntax error to refer to # names from outside of the class. It is also a syntax error to refer to private properties that were not declared in the class body, or to attempt to remove declared properties with delete.

As for why, here's what the ECMAScript 2022 spec has to say:

> [...] Although Property Descriptors are not used for private elements, private fields behave similarly to **non-configurable**, non-enumerable, writable data properties, private methods behave similarly to **non-configurable**, non-enumerable, non-writable data properties, and private accessors behave similarly to **non-configurable**, non-enumerable accessor properties.

([permalink](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-privateelement-specification-type), emphasis added)

Note that private fields are non-configurable, and the spec says that non-configurable properties cannot be deleted:

> In addition, if a delete operator occurs within strict mode code and the property to be deleted has the attribute `{ [[Configurable]]: false }` (or otherwise cannot be deleted), a TypeError exception is thrown.

([permalink](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-delete-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) see Note 1)

Note that strict mode is enabled in all classes, and because private fields are only accessible inside classes, all references to private fields are in strict mode and thus cannot be deleted.

Normally, attempting to delete non-configurables results in a `TypeError`, but the spec/engine chose to use a `SyntaxError` instead for private fields. This makes more sense because they are defined as non-configurable in the syntax (and, as the spec stated, they don't actually have the `[[Configurable]]` attribute; they just act like it).

Answer (score 3):

After reading the [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), the tl;dr is that private fields are very different from regular fields to protect the privacy.

> ### Why doesn't this proposal allow some mechanism for reflecting on / accessing private fields from outside the class which declares them (e.g. for testing)? Don't other languages normally allow that?
>
> Doing so would violate encapsulation (see below). That other languages allow it isn't sufficient reason on its own, especially since in some of them (e.g. C++) this is accomplished by modifying memory directly and is not necessarily a goal.
>
> ### What do you mean by "encapsulation" / "hard private"?
>
> It means that private fields are purely internal: no JS code outside of a class can detect or affect the existence, name, or value of any private field of instances of said class without directly inspecting the class's source, unless the class chooses to reveal them. (This includes subclasses and superclasses.)

It's even baked into the specification (green highlight is what was changed in this proposal)

[image]

Another thing to note is that you can't create a private field later; they must be declared in the class definition:

> Note that ESnext provides private fields only as declared up-front in a field declaration; private fields cannot be created later, ad-hoc, through assigning to them, the way that normal properties can.

So if you were to delete a private field, you'd never be able to add it back, which could cause many errors.

Not every specific detail is written out for their decisions into making these design decisions.

Answer (score -4):

The main reason private class fields cannot be deleted is because they are intended to be immutable. Private class fields are used to encapsulate implementation details and should not be modified or deleted once set. By not allowing deletion of private class fields, it ensures that the implementation remains consistent and prevents unexpected behavior or bugs that may arise from modifying the internal state of the class. Additionally, it also aligns with the intended use of private class fields, which is to provide a way to define hidden state that is not exposed to the outside world.

Comment: "they are intended to be immutable". This is just incorrect. Private fields **are** mutable, and are supposed to be.